# autoload and namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, autoload

Suppose I have classes in same namespaces:

directory :

> - (folder) a
>
>   - a.php
> - (folder) b
>
>   - b.php
>   - c.php

and we use namespace and `__autoload` as you see:
in folder `b\b.php` :

```
<?php          
namespace b;
use b as x;

function __autoload($clsName){
  $clsName='../'.str_replace('\\', '/', $clsName).'.php';
  require_once $clsName;
}
class b{
  function __construct(){
    print("b file<hr/>");
  }
}
$t=new x\c(); // line 13 
?>
```

and in folder `b\c.php` :

```
<?php
namespace b;

class c{
    function __construct(){
        print("c file<hr/>");
    }
}
?>
```

when we define `$t=new x\c`, `__autoload` doesn't call!
please help me :(

error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'b\c' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\TEST\b\b.php on line 13
```

Comment: I didn't have enough experience about `namespace`s  so i'm sending this as comment instead of answer. You are using `__autoload()` outside of class, is this correct usage ?

Comment: when you make an instance of your class , function __autoload should be call itself, I don't why it doesn't call itself !

Comment: Because `b` class doesn't have any __autoload() function. But it's not enough for solve problem.

Comment: if you add this code `__autoload('b\c');` before line 13 , everything will be correct

Comment: '__autoload' function is not for my class,it's magic function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined autoloader. PHP looks for `__autoload` (or `\__autoload` - function defined in global namespace) while you have defined only `\b\__autoload` (yes, functions are namespaced to!)

How to fix it: move `__autoload` declaration outside namespace

Better fix: you should use `spl_autoload_register`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see exactly what is going wrong. By the looks of the error, it appears that the `__autoload()` function isn't being called. If it was I would expect the `require_once` statement to fail with an error saying file not found, or something like that.

You could try by putting some debugging statements in your `__autoload()` function to see what's going on, including a `var_dump` of your `$clsName` variable.

It might be worth noting the following message that appears in the [PHP manual regarding autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

> [spl_autoload_register()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using [__autoload()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) is
>   discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

You should also note, that there is a "standard" for PHP autoloading, called [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). Here is a [link to an article](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) that gives a good explanation of it.

In both the [article](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) and the [PSR-0 document](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) mentioned above, are example autoloaders that you can use. I would suggest using one of these than trying to implement your own.

Comment: when you make an instance of your class , function __autoload should be call itself, I don't understand why it doesn't call itself ! if you add this code __autoload('b\c'); before line 13 , everything will be correct